# Excel VBA Originating Hyperlink Cell Address

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

`Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)`

Is it possible to use the Sh object to identify the address of the original cell that invoked the hyperlink? I need to know what cell the hyperlink came from to help with some navigation buttons to move backward (and forward) through previously clicked hyperlinks.

Sh.Name shows the originating Worksheet.Name, but I don't know how to get at the originating address.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Target` is a `Hyperlink`, `Target.Range.Address` will return the originating address.

From the  [`Hyperlink.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlink.range) documentation:

> Returns a `Range` object that represents the range the specified hyperlink is attached to.

---

Here is the code tested and the result:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    MsgBox "'" & Sh.Name & "'!" & Target.Range.Address
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Target.Range.Address will return the error 'Argument not optional'. I need to identify the address of the calling cell, which I believe needs to be the Sh object. Target will be the goto hyperlink address.

Comment: Not according to my tests on either point. All arguments of `Range.Address` are optional - from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address). And in testing it returned the originating address.

Comment: Do you happen to know what properties are available for Sh? I can only find Sh.Name as an example in the searching that I've done.

Comment: `Sh` is a `Worksheet` so all the worksheet properties.